# Image on top of div

Tags: html, css

So basically what im aiming to do is this:

[image]

However, i am not able to make the arrow (as img) show on top of div. Also i would appreciate if some1 could advice how to center the arrow vertically and horizontally.

Here is what i got:

```css
section.main{
    background-image: url(images/main.png);
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 290px 0px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    position: relative;
    div{
        height: 83px;
        width: 83px;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.5;
        line-height: 83px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        }
    img.arr{
        z-index: 100;
    }
    div.btnLeft{
        float: left;
    }
    div.btnRight{
        float: right;
    }
    p{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 316px;
        left: 375px;
    }
```

```html
        <section class="main">
            <p>Laisve kurti ir veikti!</p>
            <div class="btnLeft">
                <img class="arr" src="images/al.png">
            </div>
            <div class="btnRight">
                <img class="arr" src="images/ar.png">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, forgot to tick it as answered. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without any images, using a pseudo

```css
section.main {
  background-image: url(images/main.png);
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 90px 0px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  position: relative;
}
  div {
    position: relative;
    height: 83px;
    width: 83px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  div::after {
    content: '>';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
  div.btnLeft::after {
    content: '<';
  }
  div.btnLeft {
    float: left;
  }
  div.btnRight {
    float: right;
  }
  p {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 316px;
    left: 375px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <p>Laisve kurti ir veikti!</p>
  <div class="btnLeft">
  </div>
  <div class="btnRight">
  </div>
</section>
```

---

If you still want the images, add them like this

```
  div::after {
    content: url(images/ar.png);
  }
  div.btnLeft::after {
    content: url(images/al.png);
  }
```